# Installing PHP MapScript for MS4W

Tags: mapscript, ms4w

[image]

I have the following version on my machine. But the MapScript is not installing.

Can any one help?

Comment: php 7.2.16
ms4w 4.0.0
i3geo v.7
Windows profissional 7 (desktop)
windows 10 (notebook)
mapscript não instalado?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load "phpmapscript extension", if you're using php 5.2, you can use `dl()` function before `phpinfo()`, if your php are 5.3 of newer you need search to enable or use it.